I'm having an issue with my Gradle build process. It seems to get stuck
Here are the steps I have taken so far:
Restart the pc
Cleaned and rebuilt the project using ./gradlew clean build.
Invalidated caches and restarted the IDE (Android Studio).
deleted fileHashes.lock  file
Looked up the error on Stack Overflow and Gradle forums but couldn't find a solution.
I would appreciate any help or guidance on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!

It's impossible to answer such a question; maybe your computer simply lacks the required resources.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
